# Python - replace characters if exits and write unique to a file

Tags: python, file, replace, duplicates

I'm trying to automate some stuff using python Scripts.

Let's discuss with some example.

I have some lines in a file, suppose

> f1.txt
>
> 1. hello : world
> 2. hello;world
> 3. hello2 |world2

So I have 3 lines in the above file, now first and foremost thing to do is to replace the characters i.e

```
charDirectory = {' : ':'|', ';':'|', ' |':'|'}   #please observe carefully with the spaces and the char. which im willing to replace with
```

After this char replacement, the output might be like this

> output after replacements of characters
>
> 1. hello|world
> 2. hello|world
> 3. hello2|world2

So the output consists of Duplicate lines. Well, here is the some other file which already exist

> f2.txt
>
> 1. hello2|world2

I would like to append the lines of f1.txt to f2.txt such a way that f2.txt does not have any duplicate lines. So probably my f2.txt should have a result of

> output after append lines to f2.txt
>
> 1. hello2|world2
> 2. hello|world

Let me share a bit of code here

```
# TODO: Open a files
file1 = open("f1.txt", 'r')
file2 = open("f2.txt", 'a')

# TODO: Reading f1.txt
file1data = file1.read()

# TODO: Replace all char if exit using for loop 
    # im confused here, please help me out thank you
charDirectory = {' : ':'|', ';':'|', ' |':'|'}


# TODO: Append data to file2 - unique lines
   # im confused with removing duplicates and then write,
file2.write(...)
```

NOTE: this method will be used for large size files, please suggest with best approach.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: @HavanAgrawal i am messed up with code part,

Comment: If you're new to Python, I'd recommend going through some tutorials and learning the language. If you're struggling with just the logic, search how the replace method on strings works in Python, and the sets module for removing duplicates.